Headers error while making Discord authorization page
I'm making a website with dashboard for a Discord bot. Only when I'm making the authorization page with the help of JWT to make a token it keeps giving me a headers error (see below). I'll put my code for that specific item under here. I can't seem to find any resource for why said error pops up.
Error:
node:_http_outgoing:703
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
          ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:703:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\xampp\htdocs\discordapi\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:795:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\xampp\htdocs\discordapi\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:175:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\xampp\htdocs\discordapi\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:279:15)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\discordapi\api\src\routes\auth\index.js:109:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v21.6.0
Failed running '.'

Code:
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const router = express.Router();

// GET: designy.xyz/auth/signin
// GET: designy.xyz/auth/callback

const DASHBOARD_URL = 'http://localhost:5173';

router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(
        `https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fauth%2Fcallback&scope=guilds+identify`
    );
});

router.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const DISCORD_ENDPOINT = 'https://discord.com/api/v10';
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID;
    const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI;
    const DASHBOARD_URL = process.env.DASHBOARD_URL;

    const { code } = req.query;

    if (!code) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'A "code" query parameter must be present in the URL.',
        });
    }

    try {
        const oauthRes = await fetch(`${DISCORD_ENDPOINT}/oauth2/token`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
                code,
            }).toString(),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        });

        if (!oauthRes.ok) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Failed to obtain OAuth token.',
            });
        }

        const oauthResJson = await oauthRes.json();

        const userRes = await fetch(`${DISCORD_ENDPOINT}/users/@me`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${oauthResJson.access_token}`,
            },
        });

        if (!userRes.ok) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Failed to fetch user data.',
            });
        }

        const userResJson = await userRes.json();

        let user = await User.findOne({ id: userResJson.id });

        if (!user) {
            user = new User({
                id: userResJson.id,
                username: userResJson.username,
                avatarHash: userResJson.avatar,
                accessToken: oauthResJson.access_token,
                refreshToken: oauthResJson.refresh_token,
            });
        } else {
            user.username = userResJson.username;
            user.avatarHash = userResJson.avatar;
            user.accessToken = oauthResJson.access_token;
            user.refreshToken = oauthResJson.refresh_token;
        }

        await user.save();

        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id: userResJson.id,
                username: userResJson.username,
                avatarHash: userResJson.avatar,
            },
            process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: '7d' }
        );

        res.cookie('access_token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            maxAge: 6.048e8,
        });

        return res.redirect(DASHBOARD_URL);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Internal Server Error.',
        });
    }
});

router.get('/signout', (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('token').sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;

I've tried to remove the .send .json. status to see if that would fix the issue.
I've also tried to remove the res.redirect + token to see if that helps.
Both of these things did not work, also tried some other things but I can't remember them.

This error happens if you try to set headers after setting a body.

Could it be that calls to discord server are returning a redirect response (3xx)? Not sure this is the case, but something to look at when debug your code

@Evert Im aware of that, im trying to figure out where it sets the headers after a body. As i can't seem to find out why this error is still happening when i only have a redirect URL to my other localhost (5173) that holds my site in .jsx files

@TBA ive tried that and it has not been helpfull, ive added some extra console.logs to see where it goes wrong. Every time it leads to the res.cookie and res.redirect. Even though all of the code does function normally (only the adding a cookie en redirecting would not work)

Line 109 is in your catch block. From that I can only assume you're sending a response and then an error is thrown, leading you to try and send another response

@Phil Im aware of the catch block. This is not the problem as when i remove the response inside of it it gives me the same error but then on line: 100 (the res.cookie)

Note that setting a cookie also needs to set a response header, and thus if you have already sent body content, you will get the same error (because headers always must be sent before the body). Find out where the body content is being set first.

@halfer can you see where a body is sent because i cannot find anything.

It looks like your crash is at line 109 in your code; this looks like your last return res.status(500).json({ line. Try taking out the preceding console.error(error), in case that is being sent to the response.

If that is not it, consider throwing an artificial and temporary exception in the code at earlier and earlier points until this issue no longer happens. That may help you track it down.

Finally, consider temporarily disabling any middleware, in case something is monkeying around with your responses without you being aware of it.

@Phil is entirely right here, your catch block is triggered. You have erroneously dismissed this suggestion out of hand; if the res.cookie (line 100) gives you the same error then it must be the case that something before line 100 has sent a body.
